# referencing hmailserver com object installed on another server from c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, hmail-server

I am trying to use HmailServer com object in c#. I understand that com is installed by its own when hmailserver is installed.

But the issue is, I cannot install hmailserver on my development machine and the server where hmailserver is installed does not have VS10.

How can I import/reference hmailserver com object in my VS C# code from com installed on another server?

Thanks,

I already referred to this but does not help.
[Converting VBS code to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419594/converting-vbs-code-to-c-sharp)

Comment: To add a reference, you just need a copy of the COM dll.  It likely won't run without being installed, though.

Comment: @bmm6o, thanks i understand it wont run.. but i searched in installed locations and could not find it online too. Where can i locate these com objects?

Comment: You can either look in the registry of a machine that has it installed to find it, or you can log the installation to see what files are installed.